# How to automatic convert excel 97 to xlsx

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, file-conversion

I have a source system which contains excel 97 Data (.xls). I want to use a tool or program which can help me to automatically convert this data to .xlsx (new Excel).
After that I will use Talend or SSIS to load data from xlsx to datawarehouse.

Does anybody know which tools I can use to convert the old excel file automatically?

Comment: SSIS can read Excel 97 files natively. Why do you want to convert it to .xlsx?

Comment: @digital.aaron i agree with the `Excel Source` supports old excel files

Answer (score 0):

*First of all Sql server integration services can read all Excel files formats including Excel 97, just use the `Excel Connection Manager` for that*

## 1st Solution - Using Microsoft.Interop.Excel.dll

You can write a code in c# or vb.net using `Microsoft.Interop.Excel` library to automate the Excel file opening and saving:

**Example**

*Function*

```
private void ConvertXlsToXlsx(string strFile)
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(strFile);
    wb.SaveAs(strFile + "x", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
    wb.Close(false);
    app.Quit();
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

*Code*

```
String Filename;
Filename = "C:\\File.xls";
ConvertXlsToXlsx(Filename);
```

## 2nd Solution - Using Office Migration Planning Manager

According to this [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/524119/batch-convert-xls-to-xlsx), you can use Office Migration Planning Manager.

> The toolkit also contains the Office File Converter (OFC), which enables bulk document conversions from binary to OpenXML formats.
>   ([Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2010/08/04/office-migration-planning-manager-ompm-2010-is-released.aspx))

[Overview on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179179%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Download Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21888)

## 3rd Solution - Third party applications

Just use google to search for *"Xls to Xlsx converter"* and you will find a huge number of online and offline converters that can be used.

Comment: watch your escape character in 1st solution

Comment: @Hadi it is not the `Excel Source`, It is the `Excel Connection Manager`